# Pushing to array Added but not showing in map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, axios, frontend

I push to an array in for loop with coundition that some of them adding in another way. they are all object but diffent in condition
and then i set to useState hook

but when i show the state it shows like this

the length is 4 but when i open it shows 6

but all when i map the state it acts like 4 element

[image]

as you see the length is 4 but wwhen i open its 6 elements

Comment: Hi Twana, can you please post the code for this too?

Comment: Yep, need the code where you set the state and read the state.